# EE1 Site Not Parsing Custom Fields Locally

Tags: ee1, entries, parsing

I've just finished the local setup of a site running EE 1.7.1.

I have one issue... custom fields inside the `exp:weblog:entries` tag are not parsing at all. The title does show correctly.

I've check all paths and they are correct. I've disabled extensions, still no parsing. I stripped my template to the bare minimum and still no parsing.

**QUESTION:** Does anyone know why the entries tag isn't parsing custom fields on this local install?

---

**Debugging output:**
http://pastie.org/private/5qrbdhd95hn28sf3zfg

---

**My test template:**

```
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="static" limit="1" url_title="{segment_2}" dynamic="off" disable="category_fields|categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"}
    <h1>Title: {title}</h1>     
    <h2>Copy: {s-copy}</h2>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

---

**The template output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is because of import issues with the `exp_weblog_data` database table..

When I try to edit this entry, I see this error in the CP "You have tried to access a section that does not exist."

Going to reimport the `exp_weblog_data`.

Comment: yes; was going to suggest removing that url_title param and see if you get any records...also wondered the dynamic value, but it seems that was right in EE1, I forgot the fun ;)